# Limit each line in a text file to 152 characters using PowerShell

Tags: powershell, text-manipulation

I had a text file with multiple lines. Our software is not picking up files with characters more or less than 152 characters per line. So, I need a PowerShell script to limit the number of characters to 152 in each line.

Comment: Do you have any code examples of what you tried so far?  Could you explain if you are wanting PowerShell to feed shortened lines to your software, create a copy of the file with shortened lines, or other?

Comment: As of now I don't have any code examples. I need PS To Create a file with Shortened lines limited to 152 characters.
Our Software will not Pick up the file if the Characters in a line are Neither 151 nor 153.

It is ok to me even if it Splits each line into a new text file with 152 Characters

Comment: So, you're saying you have software that will only read a file if all lines are exactly 152 characters long? What do you mean by _"limit the number of characters"_. Simply truncate any line longer than that or should it wrap to a new line? What about shorter lines, fill these out with spaces, or ??